# bootstrap.js Accordion Collapse / Expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create previous / next buttons on each accordion body.

I can't figure out a way to collapse / expand a certain section.  I tried removing the class `in` from the `accordion-body` but that does not seem to collapse.

```
        $(".accordion-body").each(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("in")) {
                $(this).removeClass("in");
            }
        });
```

Also whenever or whatever I use the `.collapse` method on, I get a javascript error saying that object has no method collapse.

Comment: @Nofel (editor) Please don't remove JavaScript from jQuery questions. jQuery is written in JavaScript and by removing the tag, you're removing a potential audience for these questions.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The `in` class is just an indicator that a section is open. The Javascript module applies the same inline styles as `.in` does, so removing the class is insufficient.

You need to use the module's API to programmatically interact with the accordion, via the `.collapse()` method:

```
$('.accordion-body').each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('in')) {
        $(this).collapse('toggle');
    }
});
```

Or, you can condense this down to:

```
$('.accordion-body.in').collapse('toggle');
```

If you want only to collapse any open sections:

```
$('.accordion-body').collapse('hide');
```

If you want only to expanded any closed sections:

```
$('.accordion-body').collapse('show');
```

Comment: Bootstrap documentation for the above answer: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: Doesn't work.  Once you call 'collapse' on an accordion item, it stops functioning as an accordion.  For example, if you had another one open and you then open the one you called 'collapse' on, the other one no longer closes as expected. See: "Bootstrap Collapse doesn't toggle after you show, hide or toggle from code" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750907/bootstrap-collapse-doesnt-toggle-after-you-show-hide-or-toggle-from-code

Comment: `.collapse('show')` Works for me in v3.3.5.  The docs say it requires collapse.js and the accordion plugin.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another solution:

```
/**
 * Make an accordion active
 * @param {String} id ID of the accordion
 */
var activateAccordion = function (id) {
    // Get the parents
    var parents = $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parents('.panel-group').children('.panel');

    // Go through each of the parents
    $.each(parents, function (idx, obj) {
        // Check if the child exists
        var find = $(obj).find('a[href="#' + id + '"]'),
            children = $(obj).children('.panel-collapse');

        if (find.length > 0) {
            // Show the selected child
            children.removeClass('collapse');
            children.addClass('in');
        } else {
            // Hide the others
            children.removeClass('in');
            children.addClass('collapse');
        }
    });
};
```

The important part of the code is the combination, remembering the **.collapse** class, not just using **.in**:

```
// Show the selected child
children.removeClass('collapse');
children.addClass('in');
```

and

```
// Hide the others
children.removeClass('in');
children.addClass('collapse');
```

The above example has been tested in Twitter's Bootstrap v3.3.4

Answer (score 1):

This works for accordions in Bootstrap 3:

```
var selector = $('.panel-heading a[data-toggle="collapse"]');
selector.on('click',function() {
  var self = this;
  if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
    $.each(selector, function(key, value) {
      if (!$(value).hasClass('collapsed') && value != self) {
        $(value).trigger('click');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I'm simulating a click of the other accordion tabs with `$(value).trigger('click');`. According to the [API](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-methods) you should just be able to use the `.collapse()` method i.e. `$(value).collapse('hide');`. But it doesn't work for some reason so `trigger` it is...

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem use addClass("in"); only because of using ".collapse('toggle/Hide/Show');" will disturb the future toggle functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Another related use case is when we have forms inside accordions & we want to expand accordion with validation errors. Extending the answer by Daniel Wright
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12698720/6504104, we can do something like

```
/**
 * Expands accordions that have fields with errors
 *
 */
var _expandAccordions = function () {
    $form           = $('.my-input-form');
    // you can adjust the following lines to match your form structure / error classes
    var $formGroups = $form.find('.form-group.has-error');  
    var $accordions = $formGroups.closest('.accordion-body');

    $accordions.each(function () {
        $(this).collapse('show');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I did,

```
$('.mb-0').click(function(){
  $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
  $('.collapse.in').collapse('show');
});
```

and this works for me

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap 4 add the following buttons inside the card body

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block btn-sm mt-3 text-center card-proceed-next" value="Proceed" />
<input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block btn-sm mt-3 text-center card-proceed-prev" value="Previous" />
```

Add the following javascript (includes Azhar Khattak show panels with validation errors):

```
$(function () {
    $('.card-proceed-next').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(e.target).closest('.collapse').collapse('hide'); // hide current accordion panel
        $(e.target).closest('.card').next('.card').find('.collapse').addClass('show'); // show next accordion panel
    });

    $('.card-proceed-prev').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(e.target).closest('.collapse').collapse('hide'); // hide current accordion panel
        $(e.target).closest('.card').prev('.card').find('.collapse').addClass('show'); // show previous accordion panel
    });

    var $elErrors = $('#accordion').find('.field-validation-error'); // elements with error class
    var $accordionsWithErrors = $elErrors.closest('.collapse'); // accordions with error elements 
    if ($accordionsWithErrors.length > 0) $('.collapse').collapse(); // collapse all accordion panels due to the first accordion panel shown as default
    $accordionsWithErrors.each(function () {
        $(this).addClass('show'); // show accordion panels with error messages
    });
});
```