# Bootstrap Collapse doesn't toggle after you show, hide or toggle from code

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

My HTML is:

```
<div id="accordion-container">
    <div class="accordion" id="navaccordion">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#navaccordion" href="#collapseMenu">
                    <strong>My Menus</strong>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseMenu" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <div class="navigation" id="navigationcontainer">
                        <span id="menutree">
                            MenuTree
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#navaccordion" href="#collapseQuickLinks">
                    <strong>Quick Links</strong>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseQuickLinks" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <div class="quicklinks" id="quicklinkscontainer">
                        <span id="quicklinkslist">
                            QuickLinks
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#navaccordion" href="#collapseQueue">
                    <strong>Queue</strong>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseQueue" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <div class="queue" id="queuecontainer">
                        <span id="queuetree">
                            Queue
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/pdavis68/Xut4C/2/

If you remove the JavaScript code, you'll notice that the toggling of the collapse operates properly. If you click "Quick Links", "My Menus" closes and "Quick Links" opens.

If you leave the JS in, you'll notice that opening "My Menus" or "Quick Links" doesn't cause anything else to collapse, but if you open "Queue", it will still cause the others to collapse.

It doesn't seem to matter if I use "toggle", "show" or "hide" command in the collapse, it will break the toggling functionality.

Also, in the example, what ought to happen (by my reckoning, at least) is that that "My Menus" should toggle closed (which it does) and then "Quick Links" ought to toggle open (which it does NOT do.)

So, 2 questions:

1. How do I programmatically show/hide groups without breaking the toggle functionality?
2. How do I toggle things open?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1.Try to use `collapse()` with options, the `'parent'` is important

```
$("#collapseMenu").collapse({"toggle": true, 'parent': '#navaccordion'});
$("#collapseQuickLinks").collapse({"toggle": true, 'parent': '#navaccordion' });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hieuh25/Xut4C/6/

2.Basically you have 2 ways:

- Add class `in` to that div, e.g: `<div id="collapseMenu" class="accordion-body collapse in">` cause that div to open.
- Use `collapse()` with option `'toggle': true` as above, when the div is closed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ditto for setting "parent". My accordion was only behaving as such on every other click event, and "parent" solved it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Still relevant in 2021 and BS5.

Answer (score 8):

Try activating your content as a collapsible element first. I skimmed over this part when reading the documentation and it really stumped me.

```
$('#myCollapsible').collapse({
    toggle: false
})
```

After you activate it you can hide and show it as usual.

```
$('#myCollapsible').collapse('hide');
$('#myCollapsible').collapse('show');
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-methods

Comment: This is really strange but it solved the problem for me. The collapse was working when clicking the collapse/expand button without activating via js, but if i wanted to collapse/expande via js i needed to also activate it first as a collapsible.

Comment: This solved my issue too. It appears I had to call collapse() on my accordion element as a sort of initialization procedure before it would work properly. I called `collapse({"toggle": false, ...})` in my `<script>` tag; not doing so meant when I would call `collapse('hide')` the first time, it would show instead.

Comment: This was by far the easiest solution as I already had bootstrap working. adding 'hide' solved my problem in 5 seconds :)

Comment: This does not work.  After initialization, calling show or hide without any other parameters disrupts the function of an accordion panel.

Answer (score 4):

You also can add `data-parent="#navaccordion"` to `<div id="collapseMenu" class="accordion-body collapse" data-parent="#navaccordion">` and call without addional key `'parent'` like `.collapse({"toggle": true});`