# Getting a link to go to a specific Bootstrap 3 Accordian panel on another page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, accordion, panels

I have 5 accordion panels on a FAQ page on a client's site (Bootstrap 3 based).

From another page on the site, I want to reference a specific panel on the FAQ page.
I used the following hyperlink code:

Visit "FAQ 2" Section

It does take me to the FAQ page but does not select or open (**either would be great and what I would like to happen**) the specific accordion panel that has an id of faq2.

Any suggestions?

Comment: use `<a name="faq2"></a>` where FAQ 2 section starts

Comment: I did: <a href="destinationpage.php#panelofinterest"> on referring page and <a name="panelofinterest">

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to add something to the query string for the link that identifies which accordion you want the user to view.  Then using javascript, extract the query parameters and perform an action on the accordion using jQuery or something equivalent to open/highlight the accordion.

- [how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)
- [bootstrap-js-accordion-collapse-expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698331/bootstrap-js-accordion-collapse-expand)

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to avoid js if possible as I'm pretty new at this and happy to get the responsive bit working well; hate to screw it up with novice js code. I thought it was a js solution but hoped I was missing something with html.