# How to expand/collapse bootstrap accordion on panel-heading click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to Expand/Collapse 'panel-body' on 'panel-heading' on click event instead of  `<a>` on click (default), but it's not working.

Here is my html markup:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="orderAccordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <!-- PORTAL DESIGN -->
        <div class="panel panel-transparent">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingPortalDesign">
              <h4 class="panel-title before-icon">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#orderAccordion" href="#collapsePortalDesign" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsePortalDesign">
                  Portal Design
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapsePortalDesign" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingPortalDesign">
              <div class="panel-body website-design">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><span class="radio no-margin"><label><input type="radio" name="web_design" data-price="15000" value="Website Design">Website design required</label></span></li>
                    <li><span class="radio no-margin"><label><input type="radio" name="web_design" data-price="7000" value="Website Re-Design">Re-Design existing website</label></span></li>
                    <li><span class="radio no-margin"><label><input type="radio" name="web_design" data-price="0" value="Not Required">Website design not required</label></span></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- PORTAL DESIGN END -->

        <!-- MOBILE RECHARGE API START -->
        <div class="panel panel-transparent">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
              <h4 class="panel-title before-icon">
                <a href="#collapseTwo" id="mobile-recharge-api" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#orderAccordion"  aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                  Recharge API's
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
              <div class="panel-body mobile-api-plan">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-light panel-center panel-recharge">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="panel-title"><h4>Basic Plan</h4></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="s-features">
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
                                        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                        <li>Lorem</li>
                                        <li>-</li>
                                        <li>-</li>
                                        <li><a href="plan-and-pricing.html">Read More</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <input type="radio" name="api-mobile" data-price="18000" value="Basic">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-light panel-center panel-recharge">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="panel-title"><h4 class="text-center">Business Plan</h4></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="s-features">
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
                                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor dedyh</li>
                                        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                        <li>Lorem</li>
                                        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                        <li>-</li>
                                        <li><a href="plan-and-pricing.html">Read More</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <input type="radio" name="api-mobile" data-price="25000" value="Business">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-light panel-center panel-recharge">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="panel-title"><h4>Enterprise Plan</h4></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="s-features">
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
                                        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor dedyh</li>
                                        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                        <li>Lorem</li>
                                        <li>-</li>
                                        <li>-</li>
                                        <li><a href="plan-and-pricing.html">Read More</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <input type="radio" name="api-mobile" data-price="150000" value="Enterprise">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- MOBILE RECHARGE API END -->

        <!-- UTILITY BILL API START -->
        <div class="panel panel-transparent">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingUtilityBill">
                <h4 class="panel-title before-icon">
                <a href="#collapseUtilityBill" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#orderAccordion" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseUtilityBill">
                    Utility Bill Payment API's
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseUtilityBill" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingUtilityBill">
                <div class="panel-body utility-api-plan">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="panel panel-light panel-center panel-utility">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <div class="panel-title"><h4>Basic Plan</h4></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="s-features">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                            <li>Lorem</li>
                                            <li>-</li>
                                            <li>-</li>
                                            <li><a href="plan-and-pricing.html">Read More</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <input type="radio" name="api-utlitybill" data-price="18000" value="Basic">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="panel panel-light panel-center panel-utility">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <div class="panel-title"><h4 class="text-center">Business Plan</h4></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="s-features">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor dedyh</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                            <li>Lorem</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                            <li>-</li>
                                            <li><a href="plan-and-pricing.html">Read More</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <input type="radio" name="api-utlitybill" data-price="25000" value="Business">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="panel panel-light panel-center panel-utility">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <div class="panel-title"><h4>Enterprise Plan</h4></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="s-features">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor dedyh</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                            <li>Lorem</li>
                                            <li>-</li>
                                            <li>-</li>
                                            <li><a href="plan-and-pricing.html">Read More</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <input type="radio" name="api-utlitybill" data-price="150000" value="Enterprise">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- UTILITY BILL API END -->

        <!-- TRAVEL API START -->
        <div class="panel panel-transparent">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTravel">
                <h4 class="panel-title before-icon">
                    <a href="#collapseTravel" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#orderAccordion" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTravel">
                    Travel API's
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTravel" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTravel">
                <div class="panel-body travel-api-plan">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="panel panel-light panel-center panel-travel">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <div class="panel-title"><h4>Basic Plan</h4></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="s-features">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                            <li>Lorem</li>
                                            <li>-</li>
                                            <li>-</li>
                                            <li><a href="plan-and-pricing.html">Read More</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <input type="radio" name="api-travel" data-price="18000" value="Basic">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="panel panel-light panel-center panel-travel">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <div class="panel-title"><h4 class="text-center">Business Plan</h4></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="s-features">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor dedyh</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                            <li>Lorem</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                            <li>-</li>
                                            <li><a href="plan-and-pricing.html">Read More</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <input type="radio" name="api-travel" data-price="25000" value="Business">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="panel panel-light panel-center panel-travel">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <div class="panel-title"><h4>Enterprise Plan</h4></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="s-features">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor dedyh</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                            <li>Lorem</li>
                                            <li>-</li>
                                            <li>-</li>
                                            <li><a href="plan-and-pricing.html">Read More</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <input type="radio" name="api-travel" data-price="150000" value="Enterprise">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- TRAVEL API END -->

        <!-- DMR API PLANS START -->
        <div class="panel panel-transparent">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingDmr">
                <h4 class="panel-title before-icon">
                    <a href="#collapseDmr" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#orderAccordion" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseDmr">
                    Money Transfer API's
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseDmr" class="panel-collapse collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingDmr">
                <div class="panel-body dmr-api-plan">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="panel panel-light panel-center panel-dmr">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <div class="panel-title"><h4>Basic Plan</h4></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="s-features">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                            <li>Lorem</li>
                                            <li>-</li>
                                            <li>-</li>
                                            <li><a href="plan-and-pricing.html">Read More</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <input type="radio" name="api-dmr" data-price="9600" value="Basic">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="panel panel-light panel-center panel-dmr">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <div class="panel-title"><h4 class="text-center">Business Plan</h4></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="s-features">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor dedyh</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                            <li>Lorem</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                            <li>-</li>
                                            <li><a href="plan-and-pricing.html">Read More</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <input type="radio" name="api-dmr" data-price="10500" value="Business">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="panel panel-light panel-center panel-dmr">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <div class="panel-title"><h4>Enterprise Plan</h4></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="s-features">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor dedyh</li>
                                            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                                            <li>Lorem</li>
                                            <li>-</li>
                                            <li>-</li>
                                            <li><a href="plan-and-pricing.html">Read More</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <input type="radio" name="api-dmr" data-price="25000" value="Enterprise">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- DMR API PLANS END -->

        <!-- ADDITIONAL SERVICES CHARGES END -->
        <div class="panel panel-transparent">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingoAdditional">
                <h4 class="panel-title before-icon">
                    <a href="#collapseAdditional" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#orderAccordion" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseAdditional">
                    Additional Services
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseAdditional" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingoAdditional">
                <div class="panel-body additional-services">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><span class="checkbox no-margin"><label><input type="checkbox" name="sms_gateway" data-price="5000" value="SMS Gateway"> SMS Gateway</label></li>
                        <li><span class="checkbox no-margin"><label><input type="checkbox" name="long_code" data-price="1300" value="Long Code"> Long Code</label></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ADDITIONAL SERVICES CHARGES END -->

        <!-- OTHER CHARGES START -->
        <div class="panel panel-transparent">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingoOthers">
                <h4 class="panel-title before-icon">
                    <a href="#collapseOthers" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#orderAccordion" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOthers">
                    Others
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOthers" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingoOthers">
                <div class="panel-body additional-services">
                    <p>No other service available</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- OTHER CHARGES END -->

    </div>
</div>
```

Here the live: http://jsfiddle.net/8yaurtxr/

I have try to add data-toggle="collapse" but it's not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bootstrap.js Accordion Collapse / Expand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698331/bootstrap-js-accordion-collapse-expand)

Comment: its not like that as you comment @ IIGala

Comment: "_on click event instead of on click_" - not totally clear, can you elaborate?

Comment: its expand or collapse 'panel-body' by click on 'panel-heading' div @ davidkonrad

Answer (score 0):

Your anchor tag has all the event listeners

```
<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#orderAccordion" href="#collapsePortalDesign" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsePortalDesign">Portal Design
 </a>
```

delete the event listeners from the anchor tag

```
role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#orderAccordion" href="#collapsePortalDesign" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsePortalDesign"
```

and paste it in the div containing panel-heading class

like this

```
<div class="panel-heading" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#orderAccordion" href="#collapsePortalDesign" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsePortalDesign" role="tab" id="headingPortalDesign">
```

just do this for all the other accordions and it should work like you want it to

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
<h4 class="panel-title">
    <a>Collapsible Group Item #1</a>
</h4></div>
```

Comment: "Your answer certainly is worth a little explanation. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Comments would help create searchable content.
"